# How to crop the output of `who -b` to show only date and time

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

I want, by a simple command in the terminal, to ask my computer when I last booted my system and I want the answer to pop up in a text file with only numbers. I used the command:

```
who -b >> file.txt
```

This worked but it says:

```
system boot  xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx
```

I just want the date and time to show up in the text file.
Do anyone know how to get rid of the text and just have the numbers left in the text file in one simple command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
who -b | sed 's/.*  //' >> file.txt
```

works for all locales installed on my system (see test below), basically it deletes everything until the last occurence of two succeeding space characters, which should match the beginning of the timestamp irrespective your locale settings.

```
$ for i in $(locale -a); do printf "%-10s: %s\n" $i "$(LANG=$i who -b | sed 's/.*  //')"; done
C         : Sep 23 20:22
C.UTF-8   : 2017-09-23 20:22
de_AT.utf8: 2017-09-23 20:22
de_BE.utf8: 2017-09-23 20:22
de_CH.utf8: 2017-09-23 20:22
de_DE.utf8: 2017-09-23 20:22
de_LI.utf8: 2017-09-23 20:22
de_LU.utf8: 2017-09-23 20:22
en_AG     : 2017-09-23 20:22
en_AG.utf8: 2017-09-23 20:22
en_AU.utf8: 2017-09-23 20:22
en_BW.utf8: 2017-09-23 20:22
en_CA.utf8: 2017-09-23 20:22
en_DK.utf8: 2017-09-23 20:22
en_GB.utf8: 2017-09-23 20:22
en_HK.utf8: 2017-09-23 20:22
en_IE.utf8: 2017-09-23 20:22
en_IN     : 2017-09-23 20:22
en_IN.utf8: 2017-09-23 20:22
en_NG     : 2017-09-23 20:22
en_NG.utf8: 2017-09-23 20:22
en_NZ.utf8: 2017-09-23 20:22
en_PH.utf8: 2017-09-23 20:22
en_SG.utf8: 2017-09-23 20:22
en_US.utf8: 2017-09-23 20:22
en_ZA.utf8: 2017-09-23 20:22
en_ZM     : 2017-09-23 20:22
en_ZM.utf8: 2017-09-23 20:22
en_ZW.utf8: 2017-09-23 20:22
it_IT.utf8: 2017-09-23 20:22
POSIX     : Sep 23 20:22
```

---

I'll leave my other solutions here for reference:

```
who -b | awk '{print $(NF-1)" "$NF}' >> file.txt
```

will print the **last two columns** (space-separated) of the command output, which works for a locale setting like yours (according to the sample in your question).

For the english output you need the **last three columns**:

```
who -b | awk '{print $(NF-2)" "$(NF-1)" "$(NF)}' >> file.txt
```

Comment: +1 for looking behind the curtains and revealing details :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: `who -b | cut -c23-40`, and also `who -b | cut -d' ' -f13,14`

This is the output I get in both cases is `2017-10-11 07:55`.